# document.location in chrome\chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, chromium

How to make chrome\chromium ignore `document.location = 'http://something.com';` without actually disabling scripts?

The only way i came up to is MitMing myself, and that's bad solution, obviously.

I used extension-search, found nothing.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Pseudo Man in the Middle - finding `document.location = dghdfgh` in packets and deleting it.

Comment: And i'm debugging an social engine app - the page in frame redirects me to original app page if `window.top == window`.


Also, it may be useful as an protection from being pwned by CSRFs.

Comment: please be more descriptive or avoid jargons

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my native language.